# How are employers monitoring computer usage?

Tags: privacy

Every time I log into my computer I get a message that all my usage "is monitored" and when I signed my contract it stated that everything I do on the computer belongs to the company.

Obviously, this differs from company to company, employer, and probably country, but I'm wondering, how are the employee's activities monitored?

Is there a monitoring department at the company? Can my manager see my screen anytime? Does my manager get an activity report every month or is it all a bluff?

Would be interesting to hear from someone who had their computer monitored and someone who monitored someone's computer.

Comment: Hey there, what would be your goal in knowing that? This seems to be completely company-specific as you well said, which is off-topic on this site (see [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: Just as a general rule, you should probably act as though the company is at least monitoring what web sites you hit, what email you send, etc.  After all, even if they aren't today, they could start tomorrow.  That sort of monitoring is trivial to implement.

Comment: Some even counted cpu cycles per user...

Comment: Generally speaking they'll monitor net traffic on the internal proxy. Looking at https (secured/encrypted) will be visible by your company if the proxy acts as the middle man between the site and delivering content to you.

Comment: The employer can (for example) use antivirus/firewall software suites (the corporate versions) to monitor what you're doing on the computer. After all, it's (in overwhelming majority of cases) their computer to do with as they please.

Comment: As for who does that - for us, it is an internal IT department where there are people who have access and can look stuff up. Unless there is a proper cause people have better things to do than sit and observe. It's mostly automated and only pops up a warning for some egregious offences (browsing porn site, downloading movies, torrenting, installing software you should not). The managers do not have this access to the best of my knowledge, there are specific people in the IT department who can if needed, but have better things to do. Last year they did an audit of software, but otherwise none.

Comment: The issue is pervasive across the entire question, but in the specific case of _"Is there a monitoring department at the company?"_ it should be blatantly obvious that you're asking a bunch of strangers about the contents of your company, without mentioning the company. How is anyone going to be able to answer this? This is like asking if there's a break room on the first floor.

Answer (score 5):

**There are many different ways to do this**

There is software that takes a screenshot every specified interval. There are keyloggers that keep track of what you type. There is software which monitors which application is active. Monitoring network traffic is a common way of doing it, especially if you are working through a VPN all the time. There is software that is constantly reading the location.

Software to monitor employees appears to be a massive business.

Comment: I worked for an organization that literally monitored EVERYTHING, Armed guards to get in, so you can imagine how intense the IT security was

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter I assume that was defense? And did they go as far as cutting off your internet access and making you rely on books to solve problems?

Comment: No, My uncle worked for Defense, they were even more strict.  This place created a wifi network where you could hop on. with your personal devices, but you didn't even plug so much as a wireless mouse or keyboard.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter USB port is a real attack vector. Hackers do [drop USB drives near nuclear plants](https://www.businessinsider.com/german-nuclear-plant-viruses-2016-4) hoping some idiot plugs it in.

Comment: @Nelson I am well aware of that attack vector.  I know companies that were disabling them as early as 2006

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Depending on the company, that could be A LOT of screenshots to monitor. Do you specifically have experience with such tools? I think what concerns people the most is the idea that someone in the IT Dept (or worse, an arbitrary level of management) has "the right" to browse the screens of any/all employees at will. That should be concerning. It's like working at your desk and having someone staring at you constantly. I suspect this is strictly used in a targeted fashion in sane work environments-- I could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Monitoring is usually done at some level through a firewall.

But it can be done in terms of logging keystrokes, remote access etc,. if there is a need. But that would be maintenance intensive so only in a high security network, and then you'd use hardware designed for it.

Ideally you use a server and thin clients, then you can monitor anything you want fairly easily.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the sophistication of the software, they can tell when you go to the bathroom.

You can expect any and ALL of the following:

- recording of the computer screens.
- Remote Shut down
- Keystroke monitoring
- IM monitoring
- Email archiving
- IP logging
- Time idle
- last accessed
- Time logged in
- Time logged off.

AND, if you plug in your cell phone to charge, they'll be able to get into that as well.

Your best bet is to assume that they are watching literally everything, and do NOT plug any personal equipment into a work computer